# Any social media extentions?

Tags: social-media

I am wondering if anyone knows of a social media extention that allows you to integrate the public social media profiles and activities (wheter they follow you or not) of your contacts with your databases.

Best wishes, Romina

Comment: Take a look at the answers to this question: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/136/collecting-facebook-linkedin-profiles/

Comment: In particular there is this extension: https://civicrm.org/extensions/attentively-integration

Comment: Thank you william I did but am I right to undertand that it only has 1 download/ active installs  ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. It may work, but it doesn't look like there has been much activity recently.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like it doesn't work any more according to the readme. https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.attentively#bizjmaconsultingattentively